# Importing file data using R

Tags: r, parsing

I've just started learning R, so please dumb it down for me :(
When I put in:

```
nameoffile <- read_csv('nameoffile.csv')
```

and press run I get:

```
Missing column names filled in: 'X1' [1]1 parsing failure.
  row          col           expected   actual                 file
15013 next_pymnt_d 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE Feb-2018 'nameoffile.csv'
```

What does this mean? Do I ignore it?
Stuff worked properly afterwards besides this issue^

Thx!

Comment: I guess it is a warning saying that one of the column names are not present and it is named as 'X1'.  You may also try with `read.csv` from `base R`

Answer (score 0):

Something is going on with your CSV, and it is not parsing correctly.  For instance:

- There may be a missing column name
- No column names
- A blank space in a column name
- Some other weird thing

The thing to do in this situation is open up your CSV and take a look at it.  Usually you can spot it right away.